# gradle and dependency on spring-boot subproject

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I've created a project with several gradle subprojects, including: "app" and "tests".

Tests have "app" in their dependencies. Tests use classes from "app"

When I run:

```
./gradlew clean test build
```

Everything works, tests run and pass.

But when I run:

```
./gradlew clean build
```

then the tests compilation fails with an error saying that a class is missing - in this case it's a spring-boot configuration class. I run this with --debug and it turns out that in the failing case app:bootRepackage task is executed before tests:test, the jar generated by app compilation is altered and that's why the classes cannot be found.

How can I make "./gradlew clean build" work properly?

Using: spring-boot 1.5, gradle 4.0 (and 4.1 too), io.spring.dependency-management plugin 1.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't use a Spring Boot application (something that's been repackaged) as a dependency. From [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar):

> Like a war file, a Spring Boot application is not intended to be used as a dependency. If your application contains classes that you want to share with other projects, the recommended approach is to move that code into a separate module. The separate module can then be depended upon by your application and other projects.

If the proposed solution isn't possible in your situation, the documentation goes on to describe an alternative:

> If you cannot rearrange your code as recommended above, Spring Boot’s Maven and Gradle plugins must be configured to produce a separate artifact that is suitable for use as a dependency. The executable archive cannot be used as a dependency as the executable jar format packages application classes in BOOT-INF/classes. This means that they cannot be found when the executable jar is used as a dependency.
>
> To produce the two artifacts, one that can be used as a dependency and one that is executable, a classifier must be specified. This classifier is applied to the name of the executable archive, leaving the default archive for use as dependency.
>
> To configure a classifier of `exec` … when using Gradle, the following configuration can be used:
>
> ```
> bootRepackage  {
>     classifier = 'exec'
> }
> ```

Comment: I guess I could create another subproject with all the spring context setup (configurations, main(), properties, etc.) and just leave "app" mostly empty and used only to generate the repackaged jar. Thx.